# How to parse the information out of XML parent nodes in R

Tags: r, xml

I am utilizing a vendor's product which produces some interesting XML exports in a .udf file format. My goal is to be able to store the hierarchy of the XML items in a data frame.

The items are things we have built in a folder structure inside the product. The `Name` in each item is the name we've given the folder OR the name of the things we're creating (the XML calls them all "Item" whether it's the thing we're creating or just a folder).

This is a sample of the XML. Suppose that there is an unknown # of folders, and that ultimately there will be a Name and Definition that I want to capture, and which sets the # of rows I want in my data frame:

```
<Root>
 <Items>
    <Item Id="2148" Type="Category" Name="Group 1">
        <Item Id="2148" Type="Category" Name="SubGroup A">
            <Item Id="2347" Type="Category" Name="Name1"> [Definition of Name 1] </Item>
            <Item Id="2348" Type="Category" Name="Name2"> [Definition of Name 2] </Item>
        </Item>
        <Item Id="2148" Type="Category" Name="SubGroup A">
            <Item Id="2347" Type="Category" Name="Name1"> [Definition of Name 1] </Item>
            <Item Id="2348" Type="Category" Name="Name2"> [Definition of Name 2] </Item>
        </Item>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

I want the data frame to look like this, where there would be v1 - vN depending on the number of subfolders. A good enough solution would be to just pick a number of subfolder levels and assume that there are no more than that (no more than 5 levels, but needs to work on fewer).

```
v1 <- "Group 1"
v2 <- c("SubGroup A", "SubGroup B")
name <- c("Name1", "Name2", "Name 3", "Name4")
definition <- "Definition of name"

df <- tibble::as_tibble(cbind(v1, v2, name, definition))
```

I am able to get a row for each thing, with a column that says "Root.Items.Item.Item" using the `xml2` package but not able to extract the information from those Parent nodes.

Comment: Do you want them all as one data frame?

Comment: Ultimately yes. I want to compare this hierarchy to another hierarchy (another data frame), checking that the folder structure is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a good-enough solution in part with the help of an answer that someone posted but subsequently deleted (I happened to see it, and copy their code, before they deleted).

The key for me was learning of the `attributes()` function which pulled out the information I need from the lists in higher parts of the hierarchy. My solution is manual and not elegant, but it works.

Below, showing what I did to get the data down to two levels. I keep nesting these `while` loops and adjusting the logic within them, down to 6 levels deep. Assume that the xml is stored in `doc`.

```
xml_ls <- xml2::as_list(xml2::xml_find_all(doc, ".//Item"))

a_len <- length(attributes(xml_ls[[1]])$names)
a_name <- attributes(xml_ls[[1]])$Name
a_id <- attributes(xml_ls[[1]])$Id
a_item <- xml_ls[[1]]$Item

cat_level <- 1
cat_names <- a_name
cat_ids <- a_id
cat_items <- a_item

a_dir <- 1
#print(paste0("Top Level: ", a_name))
while (a_dir <= a_len){
  b_len <- length(attributes(xml_ls[[1]][[a_dir]])$names)
  b_name <- attributes(xml_ls[[1]][[a_dir]])$Name
  b_id <- attributes(xml_ls[[1]][[a_dir]])$Id
  b_item <- xml_ls[[1]][[a_dir]]$Item
  #print(paste0("Level B: ", b_name))

  cat_level <- c(cat_level, 2)
  cat_names <- c(cat_names, b_name)
  cat_ids <- c(cat_ids, b_id)
  cat_items <- c(cat_items, b_item)


  b_dir <- 1
    while (b_dir <= b_len){

      c_len <- length(attributes(xml_ls[[1]][[a_dir]][[b_dir]])$names)
      c_name <- attributes(xml_ls[[1]][[a_dir]][[b_dir]])$Name
      c_id <- attributes(xml_ls[[1]][[a_dir]][[b_dir]])$Id
      c_item <- xml_ls[[1]][[a_dir]][[b_dir]]$Item
      #print(paste0("Level C: ", c_name))

      cat_level <- c(cat_level, 3)
      cat_names <- c(cat_names, c_name)
      cat_ids <- c(cat_ids, c_id)
      cat_items <- c(cat_items, c_item)
```

This produces the lists that begin with "cat_". Then I put these into a data frame and manipulate it into the structure I needed:

```
df <- as_tibble(cbind(cat_level, cat_ids, cat_names)) %>%
  mutate(cat_level = as.integer(cat_level))

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(a = if_else(cat_level == 1, cat_names, NA_character_),
         b = if_else(cat_level == 2, cat_names, NA_character_),
         c = if_else(cat_level == 3, cat_names, NA_character_),
         d = if_else(cat_level == 4, cat_names, NA_character_),
         e = if_else(cat_level == 5, cat_names, NA_character_),
         f = if_else(cat_level == 6, cat_names, NA_character_)
         ) %>%
  fill(c(a, b, c, d, e, f)) %>%
  mutate(lvl1 = if_else(cat_level >= 1, a, NA_character_),
         lvl2 = if_else(cat_level >= 2, b, NA_character_),
         lvl3 = if_else(cat_level >= 3, c, NA_character_),
         lvl4 = if_else(cat_level >= 4, d, NA_character_),
         lvl5 = if_else(cat_level >= 5, e, NA_character_),
         lvl6 = if_else(cat_level >= 6, f, NA_character_)) %>%
  select(-a, -b, -c, -d, -e, -f)
```